# How to make events guaranteed send after service responded to user?

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq

I need to build a long running tasks service with using of external task manager.
It is communicate with user with 2 channels: http\websocket and with task manager through http\RMQ

Communication schema is:

- user sending request for task creation
- my service send it to external task manager
- receiving response from task manager and make some task data postprocessing
- send response to user with "taskId"
- user waits for task events and update task status

The problem is that in some scenarios (when task failed or its has been very simple) task events come to my service very fast, until user's request finish, because postprocessing can take a little bit longer time, than task execution (especially in failed scenario).

So question is: how to make events guaranteed send after my service responded to user?
Now I'm just using delays, but guess it is not best practice, because when connections is poor, my delay can be not enough.

The visual diagram of communication:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, it comes down to this line: *So question is: how to make events guaranteed send after my service responded to user?*

This requires some other mechanism to allow fire-and-forget, but guarantee message delivery; and, the completion status, success or failure, is relayed back to the user in some way.

This is not a trivial problem, but luckily there has been some consensus on ways to tackle this sort of thing - and some common language has emerged, which you'll find in this answer to help you with your search. The ideas generally fall under the topic of [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) theorem. But a practical place to start is with something called Transactional Outbox (see https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html)

Two out-of-the-box (forgive the pun) solutions come to mind:

CAP for DotNetCore: https://cap.dotnetcore.xyz/
Even if you aren't developing in DotNetCore, you could find something similar in your implementation language, or roll your own similar solution. The basic idea is to use a database to capture the user action. Only if the action is committed to the database is the action deemed to have been digested. A second operation then guarantees that all persisted actions are followed through with: e.g. all events for that action are sent. On 'completion', an action is marked as done. For actions that never succeed, a dashboard alerts you for intervention. This is an implementation of a transactional outbox using a database. That's the general idea.

MassTransit: https://masstransit-project.com/articles/outbox.html
There's many concepts that are pulled together to create a transactional outbox that's in memory - sort of. The basic premise is that the RabbitMQ persists the action that needs to happen (in the form of a message on a queue). You only ACK the message once the action is 'complete'. MassTransit employs some strategies to make this possible. Again, you could leverage this framework, or examine it to roll your own like solution.

Both solutions require idempotency. That is, because a failure can happen at any point, and entire process can be re-run (actions, events, etc), then they need to be repeatable without duplicates or side-effects.

In my current project, we use CAP DotNetCore for delivery that must not fail.

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for answer, seems like that's what i was looking for. Also thanks for links, because my project exaclty on .NET :)

Comment: Great. Please mark it as the accepted answer. If it is the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Yeah, its take some time, until question will be marked as answered :)